# What is the default cxf endpoint for address="/MyService"?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, endpoint, camel-cxf

If my camel-context.xml contains this cxf Endpoint, what is the default url when I run `CamelMain` locally in my development environment?

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myService"
                 address="/MyService"
                 serviceClass="com.mycompany.MyServicePort"
                 wsdlURL="schema/MyService.wsdl">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Is it `http://localhost:8181/MyService` ?

I don't want to specify the server specifically `address="http://localhost:8181/MyService`, since the application is being deployed to openshift, and it seems to function best with a "relative" endpoint: `address=/MyService`.

The above configuration works when deployed to openshift, with this sort of endpoint:

```
http://openshift-test.mycompany.com/openshift-myservice/MyService
```

So, I would like the same configuration to run locally, but what is the default endpoint? `http://localhost:..../.../MyService`

Comment: Are you using spring-boot camel?

Comment: No, not using spring boot camel. Just apache-camel with cxf.

Answer (score 0):

When running Camel in a webapp, you can use relative address (/MyService) if you use it in together with the CXF servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In such case, the resulting endpoint url will be:
http://host:port/mywebapp/webservices/MyService

Comment: It is not defined. Their values are implicit/dynamic and depend on the host and config of your target web server. If you deploy to a local tomcat listening on port 8080, then it will be http:://localhost:8080; if you deploy on a remote tomcat running on port 8081, http:://remotehostname:8081

Comment: And if you run via `CamelMain` which refers to the `camel-context.xml` and `RouteDefinition` for the web service, do you know what it will be?

Comment: Of course not. In such case, it is a standalone application, not running in a web/servlet container.
(Look at what I said: "When running Camel in a webapp")

Comment: Thats my question really. Where will the address be when its a standalone application?